# Conditional formatting and email alerts in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, gs-conditional-formatting

I want the Status column(**C**) to display **pending**, **today** and **lapsed** based on the values in the M_Date column(**B**).

[image: my sheet]

In the conditional formatting, I have used the custom formula:

```
if($b2=Today(),"Today",if($b2<Today(),"Pending","Lapsed"))
```

The formula shows no error but does not generate any output. Please let me know the error.

Also, I want to `receive an email notification` when any value in the status column changes from *Pending* to *Today*. Is this possible? Please let me know how?

Comment: For future reference, questions like this may fit better on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check what is the formatting of column B from Format>Number it should be set to *Date*. Also try to type the formula directly into C2.

Edit:
Insert the formula directly into C2. I test into GoogleDrive and it is work as expected. The conditional formatting will change only cell formatting - background color, text stile, etc. but not the cell data.

Comment: Before typing in the values I had already set the format>number to date.

Comment: I think I got it now. Insert the formula directly into C2. I test into GoogleDrive and it is work as expected.
The conditional formatting will change only cell formatting - background color, text stile, etc. but not the cell data.